# What method is used for textual representation of the data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

When you display some data using AngularJS they are presented as text. I would like to override the method used for this representation instead of writing each time something like `{{elem.print()}}`.

**Question:** which method should I define in my object to simply write `{{elem}}` and get (effectively) the same results as above?

*Longer version with example:*

Say you have collection of people, you write the repeater and inside you could:

```
{{person.name}} {{person.age}} {{person.address}}
```

But you could write for your object a method `print` which returns all that text, and then inside html you just write:

```
{{person.print()}}
```

But I would like to get rid of that call as well, I would like to write just

```
{{person}}
```

to get textual representation, **my** representation, not just a dump of the object. I hope AngularJS calls for some method per object which is supposed to be displayed. So my question is what is that method, it is not `toString` for sure, I've already checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**at some point angular gets data. User see text. So what happens between?**

@greenoldman AngularJS uses [interpolate service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) to do the data binding.

below is an Interpolating Strings Example from *Pro AngularJS* by Adam Freeman, I hope the below examples will help you.

```js
angular
  .module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("defaultCtrl", defaultCtrl)
  .directive("evalExpression", evalExpression);

function defaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dataValue = "100.23";
}

function evalExpression($interpolate) {
  var interpolationFn = $interpolate("The total is: {{amount | currency}} (including tax)");
  
  return {
    scope: {
      amount: "=amount",
      tax: "=tax"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("amount", function (newValue) {
        var localData = {
          total: Number(newValue) + (Number(newValue) * (Number(scope.tax) /100))
        }
        
        element.text(interpolationFn(scope));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <div class="well">
      <p><input class="form-control" ng-model="dataValue" /></p>
      <div>
        <span eval-expression amount="dataValue" tax="10"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Interpolation example with people data](https://jsfiddle.net/pfcqyct7/)

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <h1>Persons</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons">
      <person-details person="person"></person-details>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

angular
    .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .directive('personDetails', personDetails);

    function DefaultController() {
   var vm = this;
   vm.persons = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name 1', age: 24, address: 'Address Line 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Name 2', age: 22, address: 'Address Line 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Name 3', age: 23, address: 'Address Line 3' }
   ];
  }

  function PersonController() {
  }

  personDetails.$inject = ['$interpolate'];

  function personDetails($interpolate) {
    debugger
    var interpolationFn = $interpolate('{{person.name}} {{person.age}} {{person.address}}');
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        person: '=person'
      },
      link: link,
      controller: PersonController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        debugger
      scope.$watch("vm.person", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var value = interpolationFn(scope.vm);
        element.prop('innerHTML', value);
      });
    }
  }
```

[Interpolation example with people data (using only AngularJS Controller)](https://jsfiddle.net/phnvo62t/)

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <h1>Persons</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons">
      {{ctrl.printPersonDetails(person)}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

angular
    .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

  DefaultController.$inject = ['$interpolate'];

    function DefaultController($interpolate) {
   var vm = this;
   var interpolationFn = $interpolate('{{name}} {{age}} {{address}}');
   vm.persons = persons;
   vm.printPersonDetails = printPersonDetails;

   function printPersonDetails(person) {
    return interpolationFn(person);
   }
  }

  var persons = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name 1', age: 24, address: 'Address Line 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Name 2', age: 22, address: 'Address Line 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Name 3', age: 23, address: 'Address Line 3' }
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, angular is using own expressions, that are a little bit different from common js [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions

- Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the
  following differences:
- **Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global
  window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
- **Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties
  generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression
  evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.
- **Filters**: You can use filters within expressions to format data before
  displaying it.
- **No Control Flow Statements**: You cannot use the following in an
  Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
- **No Function Declarations**: You cannot declare functions in an Angular
  expression, even inside ng-init directive.
- **No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation**: You cannot create regular
  expressions in an Angular expression.
- **No Object Creation With New Operator**: You cannot use new operator in
  an Angular expression.
- **No Bitwise, Comma, And Void Operators**: You cannot use Bitwise, , or
  void operators in an Angular expression.

In angular uses AST parser and AST compiler that construct expression with Function constructor, `{{person.name}}` - don't uses any `toString` or others methods, it's similar to `scope.person.name` js expression.

Angular uses `$interpolate` service to convert angular expressions to html string with `parseStringifyInterceptor`.

```
function parseStringifyInterceptor(value) {
        try {
          value = getValue(value);
          return allOrNothing && !isDefined(value) ? value : stringify(value);
        } catch (err) {
          $exceptionHandler($interpolateMinErr.interr(text, err));
        }
      }
```

I think your solution is using Angular Filters.

Comment: I am not sure we understand each other -- at some point angular gets **data**. User see **text**. So what happens between? Angular builds textual representation of that data. If "data" is object for now it is simply raw dump, maybe useful for debugging but not for user. Is there a method Angular uses to compute the textual representation?